# Jquery // Hover animation is removing Focus animation

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-plugins

I'm using the "animateWithCss.js" plugin and the following code to animate the box-shadow property in a form I'm using:

```
$("input, textarea").hover(function(){
    $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0px 0px 8px #11E1DC"}, {duration: 200});
    }, function()   {
    $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px #0080FF"}, {duration:100});
});

$("input, textarea").focus(function() {
    $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0px 0px 4px #0080FF, 0px 0px 4px #0080FF, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC"}, {duration: 200});
    });

$("input, textarea").blur(function(){
    $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0 0 0 #000"})
});
```

This works just as I want it to, except for the fact that the ".hover" function is removing the animation from the ".focus" animation, and I would like the animation to not change if an input or textarea is focused and the user hovers over the focused area. Can't seem to figure this one out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$("yourObject").is(":focus")
```

to check if an object is focused, preventing the hover effect in case of `focus`.
Of course it would work with other classes (`active`, `hover`, etc.).

This is all you need to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I was too inaccurate. Here's the full working code:

```
$("input, textarea").hover(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":focus")) { // Check if your object is being focused
       // Do nothing, do not activate hover effect
    }
    else { // Activate the effect
       $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0px 0px 8px #11E1DC"}, {duration: 200});
    }
}, function()   {
    if ($(this).is(":focus")) { // Check if your object is being focused
       // Do nothing, do not activate hover effect
    }
    else { // Activate the effect
       $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px #0080FF"}, {duration:100});
    }
});


$("input, textarea").focus(function() {
    $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0px 0px 4px #0080FF, 0px 0px 4px #0080FF, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC, 0px 0px 8px #11E1DC"}, {duration: 200});
    });

$("input, textarea").blur(function(){
    $(this).animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0 0 0 #000"})
});
```

Comment: I tried that using: "$("input, textarea").is(":focus").animateWithCss({boxShadow: "0px 0px 4px #0080FF"}, {duration: 200}); and get "Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'animateWithCss'". Tried using it as a function of "is:focus", and it didn't do anything. Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are: $("input, textarea").is(":focus") is a function, I edited my answer with a full implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but still a problem. Even though you put "this" in quotes in the hover function, I corrected it, though I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function" error on the function(), after the "else". I'm looking over it and I don't seem to find any syntax error, as far as I know...

Comment: Yeah, well, now there are no errors, but it functions exactly the same as the way I had it set up at first... any idea on why?

Comment: Sorry, I was convinced of the correctness of my solution. This should be the last one (always keeping doing silly mistakes).